# Query failed : RegExp type cannot be serialized in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, dbeaver

```
select
    SUM(t138_0."mocallminutes") f_0
from
    table1
where
    regexp_like(t138_0."cosid",
    (select
     extra1
from
    table2
where
    pkid = 1
));
```

Error

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: SQL Error [65536]: Query failed (#20230324_051519_01491_fsvh6): RegExp type cannot be serialized
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.nextRow(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:183)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.fetchQueryData(SQLQueryJob.java:827)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:632)

Comment: Please post the entire query.

Comment: That's a DBeaver error, not a Postgres error.